# right use of Promise in angular

Tags: angular, promise

In my web app, I'm trying to make an edit function. For this, I get the edited entity and show a popup form. Currently, I'm struggling to get the entity. I get it, but the edit form is populated only at the second click of the edit button. I think, this is because of some asynchronous operations.

I have a repository class, in which I get the entity with the `getSender` function:

```js
export class SenderRepository {
  sender: Sender;
  senders: Sender[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.getSenders();
  }

  getSender(id: number) {
    this.http.get<Sender>("api/senders/" + id).subscribe(s => this.sender = s);
  }

  getSenders() {
    this.http.get<Sender[]>("api/senders").subscribe(senders => this.senders = senders);
  }
}
```

Now, I would like to use this entity in the edit form like this (this is the edit click function in the overview component):

```js
editRow() {
    new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.repo.getSender(1);
      resolve();
    }).then(() => {
      this.sender = this.repo.sender;
      console.log(this.sender);
      this.popup.instance.show();
    });
  }
```

Because the `getSender` method is executed asynchronously (right?), I have to wait until I get the result and then use it. But I get in the console at the first time `undefined`, and only at the second time the entity itself.

Things to note:

- at first, I'm testing this and therefore I always use the same entity (`this.repo.getSender(1)`), I will replace the index later to a dynamic variable
- the edit form has an input property of tpye `sender`, so it shows the values correctly
- I don't want to use `subscribe` in my component, it has to be used in the repository

The question is, how can I get this work correctly, that I get the data already after the first click on the edit button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to subscribe to the API calls and store data to `sender` and `senders` in your Repository (basically a service), unless you are doing some caching. Just let your code elsewhere (consumer) choose when to call your service and fetch data. So just return an `Observable` from the function.

```
export class SenderRepository {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getSender(id: number) {
    return this.http.get<Sender>("api/senders/" + id);
  }

  getSenders() {
    return this.http.get<Sender[]>("api/senders");
  }
}
```

Now in your component, call and subscribe to the service to fetch data initially as well as when needed:

```
import { getSender, getSenders } from './SenderRepository';

// ...

sender: Sender;
senders: Senders[];

constructor(/*private senderService: SenderService*/) { // Could inject as
            // service like this, but here we just import it statically for simplicity
   getSenders().subscribe(senders => this.senders = senders);
}

editRow(id: number) {
   getSender(id).subscribe(sender => {
      this.sender = sender;
      console.log(this.sender);
      this.popup.instance.show();
    });
}
```

You have moved model from the repo/service to the component, a right step to making your app more Angular.

Comment: It works now as expected. I'm  new to angular and I read this repo technique in a book. But I will then use this other technique. Thank you for clarify.